# I am just trying to display ASP.NET markup in my webpage

Tags: html

I am just trying to display ASP.NET markup in my webpage.

I want to display

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="MyID" CssClass="btn" Text="SUBMIT" />
```

This code in html div tag. What should I do?

I tried using the `<pre>` tag but it does not work:

```
<pre>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="MyID" CssClass="btn" Text="SUBMIT" />
</pre>
```

Comment: just use runat="server" attribute.get read of asp:
like this 
<Button runat="server" ID="MyID" CssClass="btn" Text="SUBMIT" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<` and `>` to html entity characters.

`<` becomes `&lt;`.
`>` becomes `&gt;`.

```
&lt;asp:Button runat="server" ID="MyID" CssClass="btn" Text="SUBMIT" /&gt;
```